# DOM is not getting updated while the loop is continuous

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

The variable assigned just before a difficult cycle. Value has changed on javascript. But the value on the dom side has changed by the end of the loop. 
Can not display loading div.
How can i display the loading div, while the loop continues.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    loading: false,

  },
  methods: {
    run() {

      this.loading = true;
      console.log(this.loading);
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(this.loading);
    },
    runWithAsync() {
      vm.loading = true;
      console.log(this.loading);
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
        resolve(true);
      }).then((result) => {
        vm.loading = false;
        console.log(this.loading);
      })
    },
    runWithAsyncTimeout() {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log(this.loading);
      setTimeout(function() {
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
          resolve(true);
        }).then((result) => {
          this.loading = false;
          console.log(this.loading);
        })
      }.bind(this), 100)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="run">run</button>
  <button @click="runWithAsync">runWithAsync</button>
  <button @click="runWithAsyncTimeout">runWithAsyncTimeout</button>
  <button @click="loading = !loading">change loading</button> {{ loading }}
  <div class="loading" v-if="loading"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, try to off-load long running task into workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about this for a while, i came up with a *brillant* solution in the form of an `onRender` function.

Vue has an asynchronous update mechanism which you can wait for after adjusting data using `Vue.nextTick` or `vm.$nextTick` (view-model instance function). But this executes the callback after the DOM has been changed but not rendered yet. If you then `requestAnimationFrame` you end up right before the next render. At this point requesting another animation frame will cause the code to run until before the next frame's render, so finally a render will happen:

```js
// This is dumb.
const onRender = callback =>
    Vue.nextTick(() =>
      requestAnimationFrame(() => 
        requestAnimationFrame(callback)));

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    loading: false,

  },
  methods: {
    run() {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log(this.loading);
      onRender(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.loading);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="run">run</button>
  <button @click="loading = !loading">change loading</button> {{ loading }}
  <div class="loading" v-if="loading"></div>
</div>
```

---

With async support:

```js
// Look at them arrows!
const onRender = (callback = () => {}) =>
  new Promise(res =>
    Vue.nextTick(() =>
      requestAnimationFrame(() => 
        requestAnimationFrame(() => res(callback())))));

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    loading: false,

  },
  methods: {
    async run() {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log(this.loading);
      await onRender();
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(this.loading);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="run">run</button>
  <button @click="loading = !loading">change loading</button> {{ loading }}
  <div class="loading" v-if="loading"></div>
</div>
```